# yescapability headerToolbar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I had a problem such that at a low screen resolution or on the smartphone screen, the calendar itself adapts, but the headerToolbar is not available.

Is there any way to make it adaptive? if you fasten the bootstrap, then the problem does not go away.

[image]

Comment: fullCalendar isn't built with mobile devices in mind, I don't think. Perhaps you can support or submit a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)